# Limit $\frac{\exp ( (1+t)^{1/\theta} ) }{\exp ((1+2t)^{1/\theta} ) }$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Compute the limit $$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{\exp \{(1+t)^{1/\theta} \}}{\exp \{(1+2t)^{1/\theta} \} }$$
> where $\theta > 0$.

This can be simplified to
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} {\exp \big( (1+t)^{1/\theta} -(1+2t)^{1/\theta} \big) } =
\exp \lim_{t\to\infty} { \big( (1+t)^{1/\theta} -(1+2t)^{1/\theta} \big) } $$

The $1/\theta$ exponent prevents cancellations, and I'm not sure how to proceed from here. (Is there a way to rigorously "ignore" the $1$'s being added within those two terms?)

Comment: You are limiting in $x$ but $x$ does not feature anywhere in those equations.

Comment: @FShrike fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's ignore $1/\theta$ and call the exponent $a$ where $a>0$ (I assume $\theta>0$ is intended). $$(1+t)^a-(1+2t)^a=t^a[(1+1/t)^a-2^a(1+1/2t)^a]$$We know: $$(1+1/t)^a=1+\frac{a}{t}+o(1/t),\,(1+1/2t)^a=1+\frac{a}{2t}+o(1/t),\,t\to\infty$$Hence the expression equals: $$t^a\left[1+\frac{a}{t}-2^a-2^{a-1}\frac{a}{t}+o(1/t)\right]=t^{a-1}\left[(1-2^a)t+a(1-2^{a-1})+to(1/t)\right],\,t\to\infty$$

Since I am assuming $a>0$, we see the expression inside the brackets is negative for all large $t$. Multiplying through by $t^{a-1}$ finds then a negative expression whose magnitude increases for all $t$ beyond a certain point. The expression diverges then to $-\infty$.

Hence, the limit is $\exp(-\infty)=0$.

Comment: Does that expansion assume $a$ is an integer?

Comment: @Peter_Pan No, it doesn't. We just need $a>0$ so that $(1-2^a)$ is negative. There are two points: identify the quantity as negative for all large $t$, and then identify the magnitude as tending to infinity. The $to(1/t)$ term is ignorable for large $t$, e.g. fix $T$ so that $t>T$ implies it is less than $1$ in magnitude. To show the expression tends in size to infinity it then suffices to show the same but with the $to(1/t)$ term ignored.

Comment: (Pedantic question:) That taylor expansion is around $t=0$, but we care about $t \to \infty$. By the ratio test, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a(a-1)\cdots(a-n)}{a(a-1)\cdots(a-(n+1))}=\frac{1}{a-n-1} = 0$, so the series converges only at $t=0$. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: @Peter_Pan As $t\to\infty$, $1/t\to0$. We don't even need the fact that there is an analytics series expansion: we just need, well, the very definition of derivative: $f(x)=f(0)+x\cdot f'(0)+o(x)$ as $x\to0$ for $f$ differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: Oh, i get it! I was wondering why the $1/t$ was important